# Visiting Japan as an Indian citizen - visa requirements?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am an Indian citizen. I want to visit Japan for tourism purpose. I don't have any income proof. I have 300,000 INR in my account. I have new passport.

What I have to do to get visa. What is the secure way to get a tourist visa?

Comment: You can visit VFS Global website for Japan - http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/

Answer (score 3):

You will need to prove the income, from the require documents page:

> - **Latest Income Tax Return**
> - **If the applicant is employed**
>
>   a. Certificate of Employment from employer/ NOC / Leave sanctioned for travel
>
>   b. Salary bank statement for last six months
> - **If the applicant is Student / Dependant**
>
>   a. Consent from the parents / spouse
>
>   b. Original bank statement of last six months for parents / spouse
>
>   c. Latest Income Tax Return for parents / spouse
> - **If the applicant is owner of company**
>
>   a. Proof of ownership (e.g. Director Identification Number approval issued from Ministry of Corporate Affairs or proprietorship document issued from bank or Import export license)
>
>   b. Company bank statement

You must be one of the above and bring the required documents depending on your situation.

Regarding the secure way to submit the application, it would be through [VFS global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/temporaryvisitorwithoutg_documents.html).

- Prepare all [required documents](http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/pdf/requirement_list_110815.pdf).
- Fill [the form](http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/temporaryvisitorwithoutg_application.html).
- Visit the [VFS Japan Visa Center](http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/visaapplicationprocess.html) to submit the documents, or you can email them from one of [these locations](http://www.vfsglobal.com/japan/india/Submission.html).
- [Track the application](https://www.visaservices.in/japan-india-tracking/trackingparam.aspx?p=ozJL6DPZmkhIHwftYnegyw==).

Comment: Does the consent letter need to be from both parents ? Is there any form/format for consent letter ?